# Getting "Floating point exception: 8" (I'm using Visual Studio Code)

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int findPrime(unsigned long long int number);
bool isPrime(unsigned long long int number);

int main(){
    const unsigned long long int bound = 600851475143;
    cout << findPrime(bound) << endl;
}

int findPrime(unsigned long long int number){
    int largestFactor = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= sqrt(number); i++){
        if(number % i == 0){
            int possible = number/i;
            if(isPrime(possible))
                largestFactor = possible;
        }
    }
    return largestFactor;
}
bool isPrime(unsigned long long int number){
    for(int i = 0; i <= sqrt(number); i++){
        if(number % i == 0){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The purpose of this code is to find the largest prime factor. I am getting Floating point exception: 8 when running it, it is in Visual Studio Code and I am running from terminal.

Comment: FWIW, instead of using `i <= sqrt(number)` which requires floating point math and lot of work, you can use `i * i <= number` which is only a single multiplcation.

Answer (score 4):

In the first iteration of this code

```
bool isPrime(unsigned long long int number){
    for(int i = 0; i <= sqrt(number); i++){
        if(number % i == 0){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Division by zero is done, but it is not allowed. The loop should start from `2`, not `0`, for primality checking.

Comment: Probably even from `2`, since `1` generally is not considered a prime.

Comment: @DanM. Oops, nice catch.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
int findPrime(long long int number);
bool isPrime(long long int number);

int main(){
    long long int bound = 600851475143;
    cout << findPrime(bound) << endl;
}

int findPrime(long long int number){
    long long int largestFactor = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i*i <=number; i++){
        if(number % i == 0){
            long long int possible = number/i;
            if(isPrime(possible)){
                largestFactor = possible;
                largestFactor = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return number;
    if(largestFactor == 0){
        return number;
    }
    return largestFactor;
}
bool isPrime(long long int number){
    for(int i = 2; i*i <= number; i++){
        if(number % i == 0){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I ran this instead and I'm getting still getting floating point exception: 8, which is really weird. I changed to unsigned long long int but then the number became stored as a negative number -443946297.

Comment: Please note that `long long int` is in general different from `int`.

Comment: `for(int i = 1; i*i <=number; i++)` calculates `i*i` as `int` and this will overflow before reaching `number`.